# SoapFault unknown error when uploading file

Tags: php, mysql, soap, zend-framework2

Running two servers,Server 1: is a Soap Client & Sever 2: is a Soap Server

From server 1, I send an envelop to server 2 with the following parameters:

client_hash (string),
unique_code (string),
unique_code2 (string),
query_id (integer),
parameters (string)

The parameters, will be a json string, which will contain: 
file_name (string),
file_mime (string),
file_content (string:base64 file encoded),
file_size (integer)

For some reason if the file is bigger than 700kb, php will through a SoapFault unknown error. While any smaller goes just fine.

Trying to debug it using Wireshark the envelop was sent but after 0.5234 seconds the connection was closed.

So I have tried all ways to increase php variables limit related on both sides but still the same,

Any idea what else could be limiting the connection?

Note:

On PHP:

```
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
```

are already 15M

AND on mysql:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

innodb_buffer_pool_size=10M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=10M
innodb_log_buffer_size=10M
innodb_thread_concurrency=2
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
long_query_time=1
max_allowed_packet=500M
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql-slow-query.log
```

Comment: Was the whole envelope sent according to wireshark? How big is the request after base64-conversion? If it's bigger than 2MB,  it could be related to php.ini settings.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/97193 for tweaking options

Comment: I think so. But php settings upload are 15mb

Comment: Anything helpful in the server logs? Like Broken pipe exceptions or so

Comment: checked logs, no errors there.

Comment: Have you tried sending the same message via soapUI ? Or some other desktop tool ? Have you checked server logs on both servers ?

Comment: Have you already determed if the error originates client or server side, btw ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below setting on your soap server slide's php.ini. Make sure to adjust the parameters according to your scenario. Most probably these should be fine.

```
post_max_size = 1024M         ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.

max_execution_time = 7200     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds

max_input_time = 7200         ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data

memory_limit =1024M           ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume

file_uploads = On             ; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.

upload_max_filesize = 1024M   ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of months ago we had a similar problem with large SOAP requests. After some hours investigation we saw a difference in the `Transfer-Encoding`-headers. A small request was using the gzip transfer encoding and the large request was using chunked encoding (You can check this with Wireshark or the SOAPUI client).

Do you have the same issue with other SOAP clients (like SOAPui), or only with the native SoapClient?! If you receive the error in any SOAP client it looks like the problem is a server-side issue. I know some older [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/chunked_encoding_from_backend.html) versions has known issues with chunked encoding...

If you only receive this error with the native SoapClient: do you initiate your SoapClient with a trace parameter? Because I think the unkown error has a message like this: *"Error Fetching http body, No Content-Length, connection closed or chunked data":*

```
try {
 $client=new SoapClient("your wsdl",array('trace'=>TRUE));
} catch(SoapFault $error) {
 print_r($error);
}
```

If you receive the error about the content length you can fix it with setting a protocol version:

```
$client = new SoapClient("your wsdl", 
    array(
        'trace' => 1,
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array('http' => array('protocol_version' => 1.0) ) )
        )
    );
```

If the problem isn't related to one of these server/client side chunked encoding issues, please add some more (server)information.

Comment: At first I tried your solution, and I though it would have fixed it, even if I haven't got the trace to work, as I am using zf2 and it seems that it won't support that option, however, the file was smaller than 700kb so the issue still the same, any other idea?

Comment: And what about the SOAPui results? Do you also receive an error with this client?! About the option; It looks like in ZF2 the trace param is true by default (https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Soap/Client.php#L1005) but it is strange that you don't see an error or stacktrace...

Answer (score 1):

On the server you might want to add: [`use_soap_error_handler();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.use-soap-error-handler.php) to have the server return an error-repsonse with the error message inside it, if the error originates on the server.

This might help you get a better error message than the "SoapFault unknown error".

Answer (score 1):

```
    post_max_size = 1024M         ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.

max_execution_time = 7200     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in   seconds

max_input_time = 7200         ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data

memory_limit =1024M           ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume
```